# @ModelAttribute execution before displaying the JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, annotations, modelattribute

I have defined @ModelAttribute in my controller, which needs to be excuted based on the requested methods output. So when I trying to accessing the my ModelAttribute from JSP, but it is producing the previous result. For example below:

```
class MyController{

 @modelAttribute("Address")
 protected getAddress(HttpRequest req){
  HttpSession sess = req.getSession();
  return sess.getAttribute("Address");// For example now Address is "Test Address"
 }

 @RequestMapping("sample.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public Model requestMethod(......)
 {
  // after execution of this method
  sess.setAttribute("Address","Changed Address");
  return model;// request directed to my JSP.
 }

}
```

When I use ${Address} in my JSP, it is displaying "Test Address", I need "Changed Address" in my JSP. But my ModelAttribute is executed after the jsp is loaded. Is it possible to make this possible using @ModelAttribute, if so then how.?  . Is there anyother way to acheive this apart from @ModelAttribute.?

Comment: Can you provide the actual code. The code you have above would not compile.

Comment: If you want the new address to be stored in the model, then... store it in the model: `model.addAttribute("Address", "Changed Address");`

Comment: model.addAttribute() is working, But this ModelAttribute method is used by many controllers in bigger aplication. I need it be at the single place and have to used in all JSP's. Is there any other way other than ModelAttribute

Answer (score 1):

`@ModelAttribute`, on a method, is used to populate the model before the request mappingmethod is called. So if multiple views need to display the address, you can add the same @ModelAttribute-annotated method in all their controllers, and the views will thus find the address in the model and will thus be able to display it.

The problem here is that your request mapping method, called after the @ModelAttribute-annotated method, changes the valud of the address, but doesn't set the new value of the address in the model. So the view still displays the old address, added to the model by the @ModelAttribute-annotated. You shouldn't have many methods *changing* the address, so resetting the address in the model should be done there, but not everywhere else.

That said, the address comes from the session, so it's already available for all the views anyway, without needing any @ModelAttribute-annotated method (which just stores the same address in the request as well). Just removing the @ModelAttribute-annotated method would still let you access the right address in the views, since views have access to everything stored in the session. @ModelAttribute is useful when your model must contain data that comes from, typically, the database: the method gets the data from the database, and this data is stored in the model (the request) by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow and use of ModelAttribute maybe incorrect/redundant.

From the official [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s11.html)

> @ModelAttribute is also used at the method level to provide reference
>   data for the model (see the populatePetTypes() method below). ..
>
> Note: @ModelAttribute annotated methods will be executed before the
>   chosen @RequestMapping annotated handler method. ...

`getAddress` is getting called twice:

- once before `requestMethod` is executed (since it's annotated with RequestMapping)
- and again in your jsp.

Each time it's being called it's returning an Address with "Test Address". You should remove the call in your JSP (by removing the modelAttribute on the form). In your case it's redundant since you're already putting an updated version of Address in `requestMethod`.

Comment: model.addAttribute() is working, But this ModelAttribute method is used by many controllers in bigger aplication. I need it be at the single place and have to used in all JSP's. Is there any other way other than ModelAttribute